# Trouble deploying pundit authorization in Rails 4.2.4 with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I am a junior developer working on my first web application for a customer, an electronic commerce portal using Rails 4.2.4, Devise and a pins scaffolding.

Devise is working great and anyone can signup and login and CRUD a pin.

Problem: Users cannot be given access to CUD as the pins contain live customer products that are for sale.

I am therfore trying to implement pundit so that users are purely RESTRICTED to read only and CANNOT create, update or destroy pins, Only the business owner can do so in an Admin capacity.

Currently, I am getting the error "Pundit::NotDefinedError in PinsController#new

1.) How can I add myself as the admin(is this through a migration?)
2) How can I get Pundit working.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:search].present? && !params[:search].nil?
      @pins = Pin.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
      @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
    authorize @pins 
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end


private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

> Blockquote

```
  class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :pin

  def initialize(user, pin)
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "must be logged in" unless user
    @user = user
    @pin = pin
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def new?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def update?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin? 
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

> Blockquote

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 include Pundit
 rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
 end

 private

 def user_not_authorized
   flash[:warning] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
   redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
 end
end
```

> Blockquote

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true

        end
```

> Blockquote

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


    has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy   

    validates :name, presence: true  


end
```

Comment: Have you already added admin for the user?

Comment: Not yet, I have been reading conflicting information on this. Would that be the first logical step?. If so, is that done through terminal or adding t.boolean :admin, default: false, null: false and running a migration

Comment: You can create a migration like you said and authorize on the admin user.

Comment: and then do what to get Pundit operating

Comment: In the `pins#new` action obtain the admin record like `@admin = User.where(id: current_user.id, admin: true).first` and `authorize @admin`

Comment: are you saying add that in the pins controller,

Comment: Yes. In the pins_controller new action

Comment: so are you inferring that the issue pertains strictly to the fact that I do  not have admin set up

Comment: Yes. When you look in `application_policy` you have given `user.admin?`. That means the `authorize` keyword should point to `admin` record. Since you haven't set `admin` thing, so is the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102392/discussion-between-chris-dormani-and-pavan).